# migrate AAD from one tenant(directory) to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I've bunch of Users, Groups and App registration and my MVC app uses AAD data for Authentication and authorization. Is it possible to migrate Azure active directory from one tenant(directory) to another ? if possible what will be the procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in for a mess.  You're going to have to recreate the applications, users and groups as they will be required to get entirely new OIDs (Object Ids).  This will correspondingly mess up the authentication and authorization across the entire tenant for these "migrated" users and apps.

In essence, the only things you can really move are services and data.  Anything that relies on OIDs (like authentication) must be reconfigured as the OIDs are associated with the old tenant.